# Callback of request is never called when I put std::this_thread::sleep_for(1)

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am trying to prevent entering in scene if some stuff from server are not loaded, I have flag bool

```
    done = false;
    CCHttpRequest *pRequest;
    // initialization ....
        pRequest->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(SceneController::on_response));

        CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(pRequest);
        pRequest->release();

while(!done) {
        std::chrono::milliseconds duration(1);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(duration);
}
```

in function callback `on_response` I set

```
done = true;
```

what should ( but doesn't work ) break out of infinite loop.
Problem with this approach is that callback is never called ( breakpoint at the first line in callback is never reached ). When I comment `while loop` it called callback.

Does anyone know what is a problem and how to prevent further execution until I fetch data from server ?

Callstack when it works on break point inside callback

[image]

Comment: It may help to show the code of `on_response`, too, so we are able to see what happens in there.

Comment: @Incubbus Nothing except I set done = true; and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Callback is NOT another thread as you might be thinking. You trying hold current function execution *'till callback gets called'*. That's not correct. You should return from it and allow callback to be called. This should do:

```
done = false;
CCHttpRequest *pRequest;
// initialization ....
pRequest->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(SceneController::on_response));
CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(pRequest);        
pRequest->release();

if (!done) 
{
    return;
}
else
{
    // Do here whatever you want to do after callback changes flag
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I tried, when I put breakpoints in both branches if and else and in callback first is reached in if and then in callback, like call is async or scheduled, it is not blocking.

Comment: In your original question callback was never reached. Now your callback gets called. Is that correct? You may need to call this function in loop that runs in timer to execute else part (after callback sets flag)

Answer (score 0):

All your code would be executed in Cocos thread, CCHttpRequest has its own thread to fetch data from server then when all data was fetched the callback you registered before would be called in cocos thread, too.

After the registration of callback, cocos thread continues to execute to your `while`, now the callback is not called (data isn't completed) your `while` will run forever. When the data is completed, callback need to be executed in cocos thread but you're seeing the `while` keep blocking it.

In async world ([see here](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/6040-what-is-asynchronous-programming.html), [and here](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11s-async-template/240001196), you must understand async), you cannot "prevent further execution until you fetch data from server" with the pattern you are using. Try to prevent it by your `done` variable in places that you want it does not be executed.

E.g:

```cpp
done = false;
CCHttpRequest *pRequest;
// initialization ....
pRequest->setResponseCallback(this, httpresponse_selector(SceneController::on_response));

CCHttpClient::getInstance()->send(pRequest);
pRequest->release();
```

and then in any you don't want user to interact with your game interface, as in Touch:

```cpp
void onTouchBegan(Event *pEvent, Touch *pTouch)
{
  if (!done)
  {
    return false;
  }

  // code when `done == true`
}

void onTouchEnded(Event *pEvent, Touch *pTouch)
{
  // Code here will not be executed if `onTouchBegan` return `false`
}
```

whenever  `onTouchBegan` return false, no more of touch code will be executed then prevent your user from interacting with game's element.
Also to prevent buttons menu clicking, set disable to their parent Menu container: `menu->setEnabled(false)` then set back to enabled when fetching done.

Comment: Thanks for reply, do you know which pattern I can use, or link to any tutorial if you had similar problem.

Comment: I don't what exactly your need so this example maybe not your case, but it will cover some. Please see my edit.